# Trying to read data of li list by ul id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my ul,li:

```
 <ul class="star-list" id="restaurant-rate">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "1" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "2" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "3" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "4" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

I am trying to read selected li data.
I have tried something like this :

```
 var interest = $('ul#restaurant-rate').find('li.selected').data('interest');
    alert(interest);
```

getting interest value as undefined.
The problem is each li is a star to rate, assume if I select 4th li this looks something like this.

```
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "1" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "2" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "3" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "4" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span></a></li>
```

I need to get interest as 4.

Comment: the data-interest?

Comment: `selected` class is added in `<span>` not `<li>`

Comment: yeah I am new to jquery may I know how to get the selected data

Comment: change `find('li.selected')` to `find('span.selected')` or `find('li .selected')`

Comment: No that din worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All current answers are right, but after your update, you need to use a `loop` to get all selected elements.

```js
//var array = [];

$('ul#restaurant-rate .selected').each(function() {
  var interest = $(this).data('interest');
  //array.push(interest);
  console.log(interest);
});

//console.log(array); or return as array
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="restaurant-rate">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "1" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "2" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "3" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "4" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Or if you want to get length of all selected elements you can do:

```js
var length = $('ul#restaurant-rate .selected[data-interest]').size();
console.log(length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="restaurant-rate">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "1" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "2" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "3" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "4" ></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just look for the `.selected` class using the `find()` function.
Then extract the data using the `.data()` function
Finally just add `.dataName`

Hope this helps:)

```js
 var interest = $('ul#restaurant-rate').find('.selected').data().interest;
    alert(interest);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="star-list" id="restaurant-rate">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "1" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "2" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "3" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "4" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

So based on the edit and comment i added the function that handdles the `selected` class

If you have any problem I'll be arround

```js
$('ul#restaurant-rate li').click(function(){
  $('ul#restaurant-rate li').find('span').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('span').addClass('selected');
})

function check(){
var interest = $('ul#restaurant-rate').find('.selected').data().interest;
alert(interest);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="star-list" id="restaurant-rate">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "1" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "2" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "3" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "4" ></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span></a></li>
 </ul>
 
 
 <button onclick="check()">Check selection</button>
```

Comment: Updated my question pl check

Comment: You added 4 selected classes. Maybe add the selection porcess. If it is for a ratting, only the 4th selected star should get the select value

Comment: yeah but I am getting value as 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <ul class="star-list" id="restaurant-rate">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest = "1" >1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "2" ></span>2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "3" ></span>3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "4" ></span>4</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest = "5" ></span>5</a></li>
     </ul>

   <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){

      var interest = $(".selected").last().data("interest");
      alert(interest);

      });

</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Updated my question pl check

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

var interest = $(".selected").last().data("interest");
alert(interest);

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var interest = $('ul#restaurant-rate li').find('.selected').data('interest');
    alert(interest);
```

Comment: Some explanation might be helpful here.

Answer (score -1):

You should add space before `.find('li .selected')` :

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the last select li element
  var $interest = $('ul#restaurant-rate').find('li .selected');
  console.log($interest.get($interest.length -1));
  
  // Use the div to parse the html of the element
  var div = $("#myDiv");
  div.html($interest.get($interest.length -1));
  console.log(div.find('.selected').data('interest'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="star-list" id="restaurant-rate">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest="1" >1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest="2" >2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item selected"  data-interest="3" >3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest="4" >4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="ico-sprite star-item"  data-interest="5" >5</span></a></li>
 </ul>
 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div style="visibility: hidden;" id="myDiv">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Updated my question pl check

Comment: Updated my answer check if its what you want